# Change the ActiveStorage Controller Path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Is there a way to customize the attachment urls so instead of

```
/rails/active_storage/representations/
/rails/active_storage/blobs/
```

We could have something like this:

```
/custom_path/representations/
/custom_path/blobs/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change default url from Active Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50128302/change-default-url-from-active-storage)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Recently, there was an addition which makes the route prefix configurable: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/7dd9916c0d5e5d149bdde8cbeec42ca49cf3f6ca

Just in master branch now, but <strike>should be integrated into **~> 5.2.2**</strike> have been integrated into **Rails 6.0.0** and higher.

Then, it's just a matter of configuration:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.active_storage.routes_prefix = '/whereever'
end
```

Comment: For those stumbling on this answer now, note that this patch didn't get into `5.2.2` and so this solution requires Rails `6.0.0` or later.

Answer (score 5):

Monkey patching is always on your side .

Just for interest with next patch, I could change ActiveStorage Controller path:

```rb
module MapperMonkeypatch
  def map_match(paths, options)
    paths.collect! do |path|
      path.is_a?(String) ? path.sub('/rails/active_storage/', '/custom_path/') : path
    end
    super
  end
end

ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper.prepend(MapperMonkeypatch)
```

and everything seems works .

Comment: Thanks for this. I consider rails default ActiveStorage paths to be a security concern in that they expose the type of framework your application is running on providing a key piece of information needed by hackers to plan an attack. I was quite surprised these paths weren't configurable from initial release.

Answer (score 0):

Tested the solution by @stwienert. The `config.active_storage.routes_prefix` option only works for rails 6.0.0alpha and higher branch. The patch is not available for 5.2.2

I made a fork for 5.2.2 with the patch. https://github.com/StaymanHou/rails/tree/v5.2.2.1

To use it, simply replace the line `gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2'` with `gem 'rails', '5.2.2.1', git: 'https://github.com/StaymanHou/rails.git', tag: 'v5.2.2.1'`. And run `bundle install --force`

`coffee-rails` gem will be required if you don't have it yet for rails edge install - https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28965