# Rails 5.2 How to overwrite ActiveStorage url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I use Rails 5.2 ActiveStorage to upload picture. After success upload , I get the picture url by `<%= image_tag(rails_blob_path(@img.image) %>`, it displays like :

"http://127.0.0.1:3000/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaEpJaDA0VW1adVF6WkROMWxrZURKNWVucG5OWGxhYTNJeFl6WUdPZ1pGVkE9PSIsImV4cCI6IjIwMTgtMDgtMDdUMTU6MTU6MTAuMTkzWiIsInB1ciI6ImJsb2Jfa2V5In19--b42277898b568d28c0ecfd555b07d0cba633b200/002.jpeg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22002.jpeg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27002.jpeg"

**When I use `<%= rails_blob_path(@img.image) %>`, I get the :**

"/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBIUT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--f9f1af07604db61f5300fd8b9aa121498cb55e9b/002.jpeg"

**When I use `<%= @img.image.blob.filename %>`, I get the filename:**

"002.jpeg"

**When I use `<%= @img.image.attachment.record_type %>`, I get the filename:** 
"Img"

**When I use `<%= @img.image.attachment.record_id %>`, I get the filename:** 
"77"

**But I just want to get the url just like :**

"http://127.0.0.1:3000/#{record_type}/#{record_id}/#{filename}",

example:

"http://127.0.0.1:3000/Img/77/002.jpeg"

What should I do to get the wanted url？ Thanks so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the ActiveStorage Controller Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49409117/change-the-activestorage-controller-path)

Comment: Take a look here if can help: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#linking-to-files

Comment: @ Mark Merritt,  @iGian thanks for your remind.